# Check is 10 minutes passed

Tags: php

I need to check if a the time between session_start and current time exceeded 10 minutes. I've tried this:

```
$session_duration_max = 10; // 10 min
$current_time = time();

if ((time() - $_SESSION['session_start']) > $session_duration_max ) {
   // session expired
}

// elsewhere I set session
$_SESSION['session_start'] = time();
```

But I keep getting 0 when I subtract  time() - $_SESSION['session_start'])

What am I missing?

Comment: You're not using `$current_time`, `time()` is in seconds, and have you defined `$_SESSION['session_start']` before using it (better check that)?

Comment: `($session_duration_max * 60)`

Comment: @santa pls var_dump values of time() and $_SESSION['session_start'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[time()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) is measured in seconds. To correctly set the timeout after 10 minutes, you must multiply the timeout duration by 60 seconds.

```
// Session does not exist
if(!$_SESSION) {
    // First Session: 
    $_SESSION['session_start'] = time();
}

$session_duration_max = (10 * 60); // 10 min

// Check if current time is larger than timeout 
if ((time() - $_SESSION['session_start']) > $session_duration_max ) {
   // session expired
   // delete session and require 
}
```

Above is a better idea of a system that would make sure timeout is honored.